# How do I use URL to fetch all posts of a particular custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, json

[image]I'm trying to be able to fetch all the posts of a particular post type on my website.  The post type should be called 'opportunities'. I'm new to wordpress so a bit out of my depth.  The posts in question actually have their on button on the admin sidebar so they could be something entirely different from a 'custom_post_type'.  Any help I could get on this would be much appreciated.

*edit:
These are the notes I got from a developer I'm trying to help:

"To access the database with opportunities from the UK office we need them to make these available through an API. This can be done by their developer by changing a few lines in their code. It’s explained at:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/
after making the changes I need to know the URL where I can retrieve the opportunities through JSON."

I'm not a developer, I'm more or less just the guy that got asked to help with website in our office.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please elaborate more. So, We'll help you.

Comment: These are the notes I got from a developer I'm trying to help:

"To access the database with opportunities from the UK office we need them to make these available through an API. This can be done by their developer by changing a few lines in their code. It’s explained at:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/
after making the changes I need to know the URL where I can retrieve the opportunities through JSON."

Comment: Do you have set the `'show_in_rest' => true` and `'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller'` parameters while registering your post type `opportunities`? If yes the you can access them with rest api endpoint like: http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/opportunities

Comment: Like default post rest api endpoint - http://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts. Change `http://yoursite.com` with your domain and try yourself. It'll works! If not then share your website URL for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers.  Where would I find that in the code to make sure it's set to true?  I have put it in the theme functions but not sure if that was right place.

Comment: In which hook? Better to use `init` hook. Is it possible to see the code?

Comment: I meant in which location.  I've gone on the 'appearance' -> 'editor' in wordpress and then copied the code near the bottom of the 'theme_functions' section.  Is that at all where it should have been copied or is there somewhere else?

Comment: Where you have registered the post type `opportunities` in code? Can you please share the screenshot for reference?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the code.  Is that the right place to add the 'show_in_rest'  ?

Comment: After ` 'show_admin_column' = true` add the  `'show_in_rest' => true` and `'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller'` parameters. Save file and visit  http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/opportunities

Answer (score 0):

I **think** what you mean is do an onclick event.

So, you *can* do this with JavaScript. Create your link as per `usual <a id=“myCustomLink” href=“#” onclick=“MyFunction();return false;”>huh! I’m a link!</a>`

And now some script

```
<script>
function MyFunction() {

//Make it do whatever here! For example:

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
```

`Rerun false;` will prevent the browser directing to the link... unless you want it to? If so then just remove this and add a link in-place of the **#** after the href.

However! A much **cleaner** way of doing this would be to do it as JQuery and attach the ID as an onclick handler. Like so:

```
$(‘#myLink’).click(function(){ MyFunction(); return false; });
```

Hope this helps!